# Horizontal Slideshow Video in After Effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects, video

I've just started using after effects for the first time and am in a desperate need to create a slideshow that pans horizontally. There are articles on in the internet that show how to do it in wordpress ,jquery etc etc but none for after effects.

Any kind of help to guide me over this will be highly appreciated.

The Images must pan Horizontally like a smooth film strip.

Answer (score 1):

Create a very wide image in photoshop (or similar), with all the images you want to use. Make the height the height of your video (1080px for HD for example).

Import into After Effects and then use Keyframe animation (you can google that term +AFX) to animate the wide photoshop image from left to right.